# Show all post titles under the subcategories of a specific parent category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories

I have searched high and low for answers which is related to this code, however everytime i use this, it only shows the 5 recent post titles. What I wanted to do is show ALL post titles instead of the 5 recent post titles.

```
$categories =  get_categories('child_of=3');  
foreach  ($categories as $category) {
    //Display the sub category information using $category values like $category->cat_name
    echo '<h2>'.$category->name.'</h2>';
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach (get_posts('cat='.$category->term_id) as $post) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';   
    }  
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `get_posts` call, try supplying the `posts_per_page` parameter.

So:

```
foreach (get_posts('cat='.$category->term_id.'&posts_per_page=-1') as $post) {
```

a value of -1 will return all posts in the category.

See [the get_posts page of the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) for more detail.